# Sitecore 10.0 Update 1 CM container Health check error

Tags: docker, container

I am using Sitecore 10 update 1 and XP1 topology. All containers are healthy except CM container.

I can see following errors in logs -

```
ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionWebApiClient completed after 0.0043ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during CollectionWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient completed after 0.0049ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during ConfigurationWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.SearchWebApiClient completed after 0.0043ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during SearchWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
```

Dependency as mentioned in docker-compose file shown below. I checked and confirmed that Id, cortexreporting, xdbcollection, xdbsearch, xdbautomation, xdbautomationrpt and xdbrefdata containers are healthy, then Why CM container health check is failing ?

```
cm:
    isolation: ${ISOLATION}
    image: ${SITECORE_DOCKER_REGISTRY}sitecore-xp1-cm:${SITECORE_VERSION}
    ports: 
      - "8082:80"
    entrypoint: powershell.exe -Command "& c:\\tools\\entrypoints\\iis\\Development.ps1"
    depends_on:
      id:
        condition: service_started
      cortexreporting:
        condition: service_started
      xdbcollection:
        condition: service_started
      xdbsearch:
        condition: service_started
      xdbautomation:
        condition: service_started
      xdbautomationrpt:
        condition: service_started
      xdbrefdata:
        condition: service_started
```

Logs :

```
2021-11-03 15:25:35 127.0.0.1 GET /healthz/ready - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT;+Windows+NT+10.0;+en-US)+WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17763.1971 - 503 0 0 157
17092 15:26:06 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionWebApiClient completed after 0.0039ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during CollectionWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
17092 15:26:06 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient completed after 0.0041ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during ConfigurationWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
17092 15:26:06 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.SearchWebApiClient completed after 0.0043ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during SearchWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:14 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:14 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:26:24 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:26:24 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:26:34 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:26:34 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
13424 15:26:37 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionWebApiClient completed after 0.0041ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during CollectionWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
13424 15:26:37 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient completed after 0.0036ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during ConfigurationWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
13424 15:26:37 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.SearchWebApiClient completed after 0.0041ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during SearchWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:26:44 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #3 15:26:44 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Agents.IndexingStateSwitcher
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:44 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:26:44 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:44 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: master
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:44 INFO  Examining schedules (count:5)
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:44 INFO  Not due: Reset Failed Automated Messages
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:44 INFO  Not due: Missing
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:44 INFO  Not due: Older
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:44 INFO  Not due: Recent
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:44 INFO  Starting: Today (asynchronously)
ManagedPoolThread #2 15:26:44 INFO  Job started: ScheduleCommand '{BA13DA26-97FB-42AB-895E-39D04BEF19EB}'
ManagedPoolThread #2 15:26:44 INFO  Job ended: ScheduleCommand '{BA13DA26-97FB-42AB-895E-39D04BEF19EB}' (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:44 INFO  Ended: Today
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:44 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: 5)
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:44 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:44 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: master
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:44 INFO  Examining schedules (count:0)
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:26:44 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #3 15:26:44 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Agents.IndexingStateSwitcher (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:26:54 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:26:54 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #2 15:27:04 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #2 15:27:04 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
2021-11-03 15:26:06 127.0.0.1 GET /healthz/ready - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT;+Windows+NT+10.0;+en-US)+WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17763.1971 - 503 0 0 148
2021-11-03 15:26:37 127.0.0.1 GET /healthz/ready - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT;+Windows+NT+10.0;+en-US)+WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17763.1971 - 503 0 0 164
13476 15:27:09 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionWebApiClient completed after 0.0046ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during CollectionWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
13476 15:27:09 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient completed after 0.0032ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during ConfigurationWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
13476 15:27:09 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.SearchWebApiClient completed after 0.0026ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during SearchWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
ManagedPoolThread #2 15:27:14 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #2 15:27:14 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:24 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:24 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #2 15:27:34 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #2 15:27:34 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
7412 15:27:41 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionWebApiClient completed after 0.0036ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during CollectionWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
7412 15:27:41 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient completed after 0.0042ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during ConfigurationWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
7412 15:27:41 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.SearchWebApiClient completed after 0.0045ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during SearchWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:27:44 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:44 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #3 15:27:44 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Agents.IndexingStateSwitcher
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:44 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: master
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:27:44 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:44 INFO  Examining schedules (count:0)
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:44 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:44 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:44 INFO  Scheduling.DatabaseAgent started. Database: master
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:44 INFO  Examining schedules (count:5)
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:44 INFO  Not due: Reset Failed Automated Messages
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:44 INFO  Not due: Missing
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:44 INFO  Not due: Older
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:44 INFO  Not due: Recent
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:44 INFO  Starting: Today (asynchronously)
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:27:44 INFO  Job started: ScheduleCommand '{BA13DA26-97FB-42AB-895E-39D04BEF19EB}'
ManagedPoolThread #1 15:27:44 INFO  Job ended: ScheduleCommand '{BA13DA26-97FB-42AB-895E-39D04BEF19EB}' (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:44 INFO  Ended: Today
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:44 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.Tasks.DatabaseAgent (units processed: 5)
ManagedPoolThread #3 15:27:44 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.Agents.IndexingStateSwitcher (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:54 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:27:54 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:28:04 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #0 15:28:04 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
2021-11-03 15:27:08 127.0.0.1 GET /healthz/ready - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT;+Windows+NT+10.0;+en-US)+WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17763.1971 - 503 0 0 185
2021-11-03 15:27:41 127.0.0.1 GET /healthz/ready - 80 - 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT;+Windows+NT+10.0;+en-US)+WindowsPowerShell/5.1.17763.1971 - 503 0 0 491
24288 15:28:13 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.CollectionWebApiClient completed after 0.0049ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during CollectionWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
24288 15:28:13 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.ConfigurationWebApiClient completed after 0.0051ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during ConfigurationWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
24288 15:28:13 ERROR Health check Sitecore.XConnect.Client.WebApi.SearchWebApiClient completed after 0.0043ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error during SearchWebApiClient initialization: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'
ManagedPoolThread #3 15:28:14 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #3 15:28:14 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #3 15:28:24 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #3 15:28:24 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
ManagedPoolThread #2 15:28:34 INFO  Job started: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent
ManagedPoolThread #2 15:28:34 INFO  Job ended: Sitecore.ListManagement.Operations.UpdateListOperationsAgent (units processed: )
```

Comment: Likely because it fails on mssql. But you will need to post actual logs for anyone to have a reasonable idea.

Comment: @MarkCassidy  Added logs.

Comment: @Siddharth did you get a solution for this?

Comment: @Siddharth any update on this ticket?

Comment: @nologo There are couple of things you can try-

1. Check if solr is up and running. Access Solr service by Url- http://localhost:8984/. If you have configured any other port number , try with that.

2. Access CM website directly using - http://localhost:8082/, it will give you exact error.

3. Disable health check for CM -
    healthcheck:
          disable: true

4. Go inside CM container by command - docker exec -it XXXX powershell  (XXXX is container Id) and then run command -
 Invoke-WebRequest -uri http://localhost -UseBasicParsing

Comment: @Siddharth thanks mate! my issue was running XP in CMS Only mode (xdb disabled) however the sitecore healthcheck is actually checking xconnect .. so really doesn't make any sense that XP can run in CMS only mode if the health check hasn't been fixed..
updated healthcheck to be service_started and its working.
thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue to this for CM, CD and XC Search on Sitecore 10.3. The health check `[instanceurl]/healthz/live` returned 'Healthy' but the `[instanceurl]/healthz/ready` one returned 'Unhealthy'.

The error related to this in the logs was re my cores:

```
Health check sitecore_master_index completed after 6.7257ms with status Unhealthy and 'Error message: <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=ISO-8859...
```

It turned out that my config for my Solr cores was not correct in Solr, there was a miss-match in the name of the core in the core.properties file and what I had configured in Sitecore. My instances are now all in 'ready' state

**So in summary:**

1. Check your Solr Connection string is correct (it requires the end / I believe)
2. Check Solr is up and running and accessible
3. Check you have created all Solr Cores listed here: https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/search-index-descriptions.html
   and configured them as described here:
   https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/103/platform-administration-and-architecture/walkthrough--setting-up-solr.html
4. Check your Core configuration in Solr (e.g Schema and naming in core.properties)
5. Check [cm-instance-url]/sitecore/admin/Showconfig.aspx and ensure that Solr is enabled and the correct search provider config is in place and all required Cores are configured with the correct names.

When making any changes to Solr or Sitecore you may need to re-start them and also clear the Event Queue and History tables to get the Sitecore Indexing Manager to show the cores correctly and show healthy/ready response.